# Papers regarding panel data with autoregressive errors

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, autoregressive

I've been playing around, using the fixed effects and first difference models to estimate regression coefficient for DGP:s that have autoregressive error terms, and I'm wondering if anybody knows of some paper or research that has been done in this particular field, taking a more theoretical look at the properties of the estimates?

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently writing two papers on these issues. Please find the working versions here: https://github.com/ACL90/rho_xtregar/blob/master/The_estimation_of_the_autocorrelation_coefficient_in_a_panel_data_model_with_AR_1__disturbances.pdf

and here: https://github.com/ACL90/rho_xtregar/blob/master/fixed_effects_AR1_and_the_variance_of_the_perturbations_v1_0_0.pdf

(These are ongoing works. Feedbacks are really appreciated)

You will find within some published references, among those:
Baltagi, B. H., & Wu, P. X. (1999). Unequally spaced panel data regressions with AR (1) disturbances. Econometric Theory, 15(6), 814-823.

Bhargava, A., Franzini, L., & Narendranathan, W. (1982). Serial correlation and the fixed effects model. The Review of Economic Studies, 49(4), 533-549.